# Cookies in Angular 4

Tags: angularjs, typescript, cookies, angular

I am trying to create an easy website. I came across Angular 4 a thought this would be a nice fit for my needs. So I started to mess around and tried to create something.

Now I am trying to set a Cookie. I searched quite a lot, but all I found were some older versions of Angular which didn't really help me along. They were written in JavaScript, used $cookies and the examples were completely different structured. I am using TypeScript.

**Can you show how to set a cookie in Angular 4 and TypeScript?**

I am just programming for fun, so please don't expect that much knowledge.
But I am willing to learn.

Thank you very much and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please try it by yourself first and then ask the questions. We are here to help if you are stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You CANNOT set a cookie from the front end. The cookie needs to be sent from the server with a `set-cookie` header.

And NO! Angular 4 is not known as Angular 2. HOWEVER, Angular 4 drives a lot of similarities from Angular 2 and is built under the same architecture, hence, what works in Angular 2 works for Angular 4, most of the times.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, turns out I'm really stupid. The newest angular-version is 4 but its known as angular 2. So I found my answer really fast.

Sorry for my stupidity.